# Add new attribute (element) to JSON object using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

How do I add new attribute (element) to JSON object using JavaScript?

Answer (score 748):

JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation.  A JSON object is really a string that has yet to be turned into the object it represents.

To add a property to an existing object in JS you could do the following.

```
object["property"] = value;
```

or

```
object.property = value;
```

If you provide some extra info like exactly what you need to do in context you might get a more tailored answer.

Comment: is this possible then:

object["property"]["subProperty"]... that would be amazing.

Just tried. var a.s = "what"; a.s.d = "nope";

It's undefined :(

Comment: @shanehoban here `a` is JSON, `a.s` as just defined by you is a string. Now you are trying to add `["subproperty"]` to a string. Do you understand now why u got the error?

Comment: For beginners, remember that as Quintin says, a JSON "object" is not an object at all, it's just a string.  You would need to convert it to an actual Javascript object with JSON.parse() before using his example of
`object["property"] = value;`

Comment: @shanehoban check my answer on the top and you'll see how you can add multiple attributes at once.

Comment: For a newbie like me, it is worth mentioning that object declaration should be like var j = {}. Above assignment will not work if object is declared as var j;.

Comment: If you run this code... `var object = {}; object["property"] = "value"; console.log(object);` ...the output will result in an invalid JSON since a string is expected for the attribute name "property". Maybe I misunderstood, but what generates a valid JSON would be the command... `var object = {}; object["\"property\""] = "value"; console.log(object);` ...so I think it would be important to clarify this. Thanks! =D

Comment: @EduardoLucio That's because you should be using `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: @SolomonUcko The command `var object = {}; object["property"] = "value"; console.log(object);` will generate this INVALID JSON on my chrome console: `{property: "value"}`. But, the command `var object = {}; object["\"property\""] = "value"; console.log(object);` will generate this VALID JSON on my chrome console: `{"property": "value"}`. You can test on this website https://jsonlint.com/ . =D

Comment: @EduardoLucio The issue is that `console.log` is not intended for serialization. Use `console.log(JSON. stringify(object))`.

Answer (score 220):

```
var jsonObj = {
    members: 
           {
            host: "hostName",
            viewers: 
            {
                user1: "value1",
                user2: "value2",
                user3: "value3"
            }
        }
}

var i;

for(i=4; i<=8; i++){
    var newUser = "user" + i;
    var newValue = "value" + i;
    jsonObj.members.viewers[newUser] = newValue ;

}

console.log(jsonObj);
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for, adding an element when the name must be constructed programmatically

Comment: when jsonObj in itself would contain more than one element, then: ---> jsonObj["members"].anyname = "value"; <--- adds an element at the first level. This is particulary interesting in a situation like: ---> for (var key in jsonObj ) {  jsonObj[key].newAttrib= 'something '; }

Answer (score 170):

A JSON object is simply a javascript object, so with Javascript being a prototype based language, all you have to do is address it using the dot notation.

```
mything.NewField = 'foo';
```

Comment: That is it, i love javascript protoype!

Answer (score 132):

With ECMAScript since 2015 you can use Spread Syntax ( …three dots):

```
let  people = { id: 4 ,firstName: 'John'};
people = { ...people, secondName: 'Fogerty'};
```

It's allow you to add sub objects:

```
people = { ...people, city: { state: 'California' }};
```

the result would be:

```
{  
   "id": 4,
   "firstName": "John",
   "secondName": "Forget",
   "city": {  
      "state": "California"
   }
}
```

You also can merge objects:

```
var mergedObj = { ...obj1, ...obj2 };
```

Answer (score 81):

thanks for this post. I want to add something that can be useful.

For IE, it is good to use

```
object["property"] = value;
```

syntax because some special words in IE can give you an error.

An example:

```
object.class = 'value';
```

this fails in IE, because "**class**" is a special word. I spent several hours with this.

Comment: @Sunil Garg How would you store that value as a child to some parent in the original object?

Answer (score 17):

You can also use `Object.assign` from `ECMAScript 2015`. It also allows you to add nested attributes at once. E.g.:

```
const myObject = {};

Object.assign(myObject, {
    firstNewAttribute: {
        nestedAttribute: 'woohoo!'
    }
});
```

Ps: This will not override the existing object with the assigned attributes. Instead they'll be added. However if you assign a value to an existing attribute then it would be overridden.

Answer (score 7):

```
extend: function(){
    if(arguments.length === 0){ return; }
    var x = arguments.length === 1 ? this : arguments[0];
    var y;

    for(var i = 1, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
        y = arguments[i];
        for(var key in y){
            if(!(y[key] instanceof Function)){
                x[key] = y[key];
            }
        }           
    };

    return x;
}
```

Extends multiple json objects (ignores functions):

```
extend({obj: 'hej'}, {obj2: 'helo'}, {obj3: {objinside: 'yes'}});
```

Will result in a single json object

Answer (score 6):

You can also dynamically add attributes with variables directly in an object literal.

```
const amountAttribute = 'amount';
const foo = {
                [amountAttribute]: 1
            };
foo[amountAttribute + "__more"] = 2;
```

Results in:

```
{
    amount: 1, 
    amount__more: 2
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also add new json objects into your json, using the [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) function,

```
var newJson = $.extend({}, {my:"json"}, {other:"json"});
// result -> {my: "json", other: "json"}
```

A very good option for the extend function is the recursive merge. Just add the true value as the first parameter (read the documentation for more options). Example,

```
var newJson = $.extend(true, {}, {
    my:"json",
    nestedJson: {a1:1, a2:2}
}, {
    other:"json",
    nestedJson: {b1:1, b2:2}
});
// result -> {my: "json", other: "json", nestedJson: {a1:1, a2:2, b1:1, b2:2}}
```

Comment: `extend()` is part of jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Uses `$.extend()` of **jquery**, like this:

```
token = {_token:window.Laravel.csrfToken};
data = {v1:'asdass',v2:'sdfsdf'}
dat = $.extend(token,data);
```

I hope you serve them.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me for add a new field named 'id'.
Angular Slickgrid usually needs such id

```
  addId() {
     this.apiData.forEach((item, index) => {
     item.id = index+1;
  });
```