# How do I incrementally build and tear down a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I need a user to be able to perform these actions:

1. Click an "Add" button. This will add a JavaScript object to either an array, or another JavaScript object.
2. Click a dynamic "Remove" button. This will remove the JavaScript object from the array, or object, whose ID matches the button click.
3. Submit the complete array, or object, of desired objects server-side for processing.

**Using an array, am I able to get a handle via ID on a specific element and remove it with a "pop"-like function?**  If not, am I able to do so using a JavaScript object?

This question is related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736590/how-do-i-add-new-attribute-element-to-json-object-using-javascript), but there isn't much context in the original to answer my question.  Thanks!

Comment: By the way, there's no such thing as a "JSON object"; you mean a Javascript object.  JSON is just a format used to serialize an object to a string.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have edited the post based on all of your comments and have voted you both up for getting me on the right track and using the right terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may actually be better to use an object rather than an array. This will allow you to name each object you send back to the server.

```
var dataObject = {};

function addData(name, data1, data2, data3) {
    dataObject[name] = {
        data1: data1,
        data2: data2,
        data3: data3        
    };
}

function removeData(name) {
    delete dataObject[name];
}
```

Comment: That depends on what he's doing.

Comment: "may" being the key word in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can append an element to an array using the [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/push) method, like this:

```
var someArray = [];    //Start with an empty array

//Later,
someArray.push({ name: 'value' });
```