# How to add new object in JSON using jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, json

I want to add new obj of `JSON` like:

```
    "128": {
        "Msg": [{
            "me": "hi"
        }, {
            "user": "hello"
        }, {
            "me": "whtup"
        }]
    }
```

In the exist `JSON` object Example of `JSON` :

```
{
    "188": {
        "Msg": [{
            "me": "hi"
        }, {
            "user": "hello"
        }, {
            "me": "ki chal riha hai"
        }]
    },
    "123": {
        "Msg": [{
            "me": "hi"
        }, {
            "user": "hello"
        }, {
            "me": "whtup"
        }]
    },
    "128": {
        "Msg": [{
            "me": "hi"
        }, {
            "user": "hello"
        }, {
            "me": "whtup"
        }]
    }
```

Comment: Please have look on this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736590/how-do-i-add-new-attribute-element-to-json-object-using-javascript

Comment: i want to add json obj in json this is for add data in array type of json obj

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JSON stands for JavaScript object notation. So, it's nothing but an object ( actually a subset of object ) in javascript.

So, actually you want to add an object in existing javascript object.

Also, jQuery is nothing but a library (collections of different javascript functions to ease selecting dom elements, ajax functions, and some other utilities)

Coming back to your question,

If this is your existing object,

```
var obj = {
    "188": {
        "Msg": [{
            "me": "hi"
        }, {
            "user": "hello"
        }, {
            "me": "ki chal riha hai"
        }]
    },
    "123": {
        "Msg": [{
            "me": "hi"
        }, {
            "user": "hello"
        }, {
            "me": "whtup"
        }]
    },
    "128": {
        "Msg": [{
            "me": "hi"
        }, {
            "user": "hello"
        }, {
            "me": "whtup"
        }]
    }
}
```

You can add

```
  var objToAdd =  {
            "Msg": [{
                "me": "hi"
            }, {
                "user": "hello"
            }, {
                "me": "whtup"
            }]
        }
```

by,

```
obj["128"] = objToAdd;
```

Now, your `obj` is,

```
{
        "188": {
            "Msg": [{
                "me": "hi"
            }, {
                "user": "hello"
            }, {
                "me": "ki chal riha hai"
            }]
        },
        "123": {
            "Msg": [{
                "me": "hi"
            }, {
                "user": "hello"
            }, {
                "me": "whtup"
            }]
        },
        "128":{
            "Msg": [{
                "me": "hi"
            }, {
                "user": "hello"
            }, {
                "me": "whtup"
            }]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just replace the value for key "128" (as opposed to creating a duplicate entry for it, as you've shown)?