# Get/iterate over properties that are not in object

Tags: jquery, css, object, for-loop, styles

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677311/merge-json-object-and-populate-next-prev-items), I need to chek if a property is not in an object:

So, we've some styling:

```
.foo {
    top: 13px;
    width: 37px;
}
```

...and an object like this one:

```
var keyframe = {
    0: {
        top: 0
    },
    1000: {
        top: 100
    },
    2000: {
        width: 100
    }
};
```

now I need to iterate over all properties that are not in the next/previous *frame*-item, to populate the missing property with the css-values from an jQuery-object.

So that the final object looks like this:

```
var keyframe = {
    0: {
        top: 0,
        width: '37px'
    },
    1000: {
        top: 100,
        width: '37px'
    },
    2000: {
        top: 100,
        width: 100
    }
};
```

I've tried something like this:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/WdNge/

```
var $foo = $('.foo');
for (var key in keyframe) {
    var obj = keyframe[key];
    for(var ok in obj) {
        if (!(ok in obj)) obj[ok] = $foo.css(ok);
    }
}
```

**But** it seems that

```
if (!(ok in obj)) // is always `truthy`
```

however if I declare it directly

```
if (!('top' in obj)) // it works...
```

Any ideas?

**Update**

I even tried something like this, but no success:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/WdNge/1/

```
var $foo = $('.foo');
var keys = [];
for (var key in keyframe) {
    var obj = keyframe[key];
    var k = Object.keys(obj);
    keys.push(k[0]);
    for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var ok = keys[i];
        if (!(ok in obj)) obj[ok] = $foo.css(ok);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, `for ... in` iterates over existing properties of the object, so the test `prop in obj` will always be true.

Comment: You need a separate array or object that lists all the required keys of an object. You iterate over that array, and check whether the key is in `obj`.

Comment: @Barmar See my update... Maybe a problem in my logic?

Comment: where that `ok` came from?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui Whoops, forgot to add `ok = keys[i];`, updated it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you can't extract the specified CSS properties from a class using jQuery/Javascript.

That means that you'll have to a) store the `.foo` class specification separately as JSON within your Javascript or b) iterate over all CSS properties that jQuery is aware of.

CSS

```
.foo {
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Javascript

```
var foo_styles = { top: 0, width: "100px" },
    keyframe = {
    0: {
        top: 0
    },
    1000: {
        top: 100
    },
    2000: {
        width: 100
    }
};
for (var key in keyframe) {
    var frame = keyframe[key];
    for(var frameProperty in foo_styles) {
        if (!(frameProperty in frame)) {
            frame[frameProperty] = foo_styles[frameProperty];
        } else {
            // Update with last value from keyframe
            foo_styles[frameProperty] = frame[frameProperty];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Looks good so far, problem is, that `top` is `0` in the last frame, and not `100`...

Comment: @yckart I've made an update that will overwrite the `foo_styles` values if `keyframe` has that CSS property already

Comment: @yckart I think thg435's answer to your original question is much much better than this!