# append data to a JS "JSON array"

Tags: javascript, node.js

In JS (it is node/js but actually is a general JS question)

I have a data object which is a result of JSON coming from the server.

I want to manipulate the data before passing it to the view.

How can I do that? (I can make additional objects that contain the rest of the data but it feels wrong and un-natural)

```
var response = JSON.parse(moment_respose_content );
if (response.success)
{
    var data = response.data[0];
    //add additional fields to data
}
```

Comment: Could you show us an example of the returned JSON?

Comment: That is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This may have already been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736590/add-new-attribute-element-to-json-object-using-javascript)

A JSON object is just a JS object, you can add/edit/remove parts like you would any other.

Comment: If the question is a (possible) duplicate, you can vote to close or flag it.

Comment: @BenFortune I have marked it as such. Also, why is this answer getting voted down?