# How to push a array of json to array of json?

Tags: javascript, json

My existing array of json coming from response is:

```
comments:[{id: "3124fac5-9d3e-4fa9-8a80-10f626fbf141", createdDate: 1469606019000,…},…]
0:{id: "3124fac5-9d3e-4fa9-8a80-10f626fbf141", createdDate: 1469606019000,…}
createdBy:{id: "cf2829b7-0c76-4a08-9562-ccbfa012ef2d", createdDate: 1469605771000, name: "user",…}
createdDate:1469606019000
id:"3124fac5-9d3e-4fa9-8a80-10f626fbf141"
lastModifiedBy:{id: "cf2829b7-0c76-4a08-9562-ccbfa012ef2d", createdDate: 1469605771000, name: "user",…}
lastModifiedDate:1469606019000
message:"twrey"
1:{id: "350fd2bd-f452-495c-9bd5-79aa7c799d02", createdDate: 1469619161000,…}
createdBy:{id: "cf2829b7-0c76-4a08-9562-ccbfa012ef2d", createdDate: 1469605771000, name: "user",…}
createdDate:1469619161000
id:"350fd2bd-f452-495c-9bd5-79aa7c799d02"
lastModifiedBy:{id: "cf2829b7-0c76-4a08-9562-ccbfa012ef2d", createdDate: 1469605771000, name: "user",…}
lastModifiedDate:1469619161000
message:"yuo"
```

I want to push a files array of json to existing comments array of json, the result of json should look like this:

```
comments:[{id: "3124fac5-9d3e-4fa9-8a80-10f626fbf141", createdDate: 1469606019000,…},…]
0:{id: "3124fac5-9d3e-4fa9-8a80-10f626fbf141", createdDate: 1469606019000,…}
createdBy:{id: "cf2829b7-0c76-4a08-9562-ccbfa012ef2d", createdDate: 1469605771000, name: "user",…}
createdDate:1469606019000
id:"3124fac5-9d3e-4fa9-8a80-10f626fbf141"
lastModifiedBy:{id: "cf2829b7-0c76-4a08-9562-ccbfa012ef2d", createdDate: 1469605771000, name: "user",…}
lastModifiedDate:1469606019000
message:"twrey"
files:[]
1:{id: "350fd2bd-f452-495c-9bd5-79aa7c799d02", createdDate: 1469619161000,…}
createdBy:{id: "cf2829b7-0c76-4a08-9562-ccbfa012ef2d", createdDate: 1469605771000, name: "user",…}
createdDate:1469619161000
id:"350fd2bd-f452-495c-9bd5-79aa7c799d02"
lastModifiedBy:{id: "cf2829b7-0c76-4a08-9562-ccbfa012ef2d", createdDate: 1469605771000, name: "user",…}
lastModifiedDate:1469619161000
message:"yuo"
files:[]
```

Comment: Question title should be like  `add a property to existing json object` its simply about having beginner know how of json
Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736590/add-new-attribute-element-to-json-object-using-javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You need only to add a property to jsonObject just write. Yo just need to know about how to 
[Add new attribute (element) to JSON object using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736590/add-new-attribute-element-to-json-object-using-javascript)

```
yourCurrentJSONObject.propertyNameToAdd = yourFilesArray;
```

Example

```
var yourCurrentJSONObject = {
comments:[{id: "3124fac5-9d3e-4fa9-8a80-10f626fbf141", createdDate: 1469606019000,…},…]
0:{id: "3124fac5-9d3e-4fa9-8a80-10f626fbf141", createdDate: 1469606019000,…}
createdBy:{id: "cf2829b7-0c76-4a08-9562-ccbfa012ef2d", createdDate: 1469605771000, name: "user",…}
createdDate:1469606019000
id:"3124fac5-9d3e-4fa9-8a80-10f626fbf141"
lastModifiedBy:{id: "cf2829b7-0c76-4a08-9562-ccbfa012ef2d", createdDate: 1469605771000, name: "user",…}
lastModifiedDate:1469606019000
message:"twrey"
1:{id: "350fd2bd-f452-495c-9bd5-79aa7c799d02", createdDate: 1469619161000,…}
createdBy:{id: "cf2829b7-0c76-4a08-9562-ccbfa012ef2d", createdDate: 1469605771000, name: "user",…}
createdDate:1469619161000
id:"350fd2bd-f452-495c-9bd5-79aa7c799d02"
lastModifiedBy:{id: "cf2829b7-0c76-4a08-9562-ccbfa012ef2d", createdDate: 1469605771000, name: "user",…}
lastModifiedDate:1469619161000
message:"yuo"
}


var yourFilesArray = [....];
yourCurrentJSONObject['files'] = yourFilesArray;
//    or simply
yourCurrentJSONObject.files = yourFilesArray;
```

If you can console the array after above instruction you will see, it includes files array alogwith comments and the message

Answer (score 0):

If you have two arrays of objects and you want to merge them I'd go with [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Of course the two arrays have to be of the same length

```js
var a = [{id: 1, asd: 2}, {id: 2, asd: 3}];
var b = [{files: 'asd'}, {files: 'dsa'}];

var c = a.map((obj, i) => Object.assign(obj, b[i]));

console.log(c)
```