# add a element to json array with Key/value using angular js

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json

I have a json array object like below

$scope.Json = [{
  Id:"5464",
  Class:"9",
  Rank:"4"
}]

I want to add a item "Name":"Vicky" to the Json. So that my result should be as below.

$scope.Json = [{
  Id:"5464",
  Class:"9",
  Rank:"4",
  Name:"Vicky"
}]

I am new to angular, can anyone help on this?

Comment: Publicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736590/add-new-attribute-element-to-json-object-using-javascript - please search before asking a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Use Array [**map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

**DEMO**

```js
var json = [{ Id:"5464", Class:"9", Rank:"4" }];

json.map(function(item) {
  item.Name = 'Vicky'; 
});

console.log(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the object `$scope.Json` is not a JSON but a string. To get a JSON, you need to parse the string like the following:

```
$scope.Json = JSON.parse(<string>) ;
```

Second, your input is a **peculiar** JSON as it is an array with one element (in its turn having 3 elements. I guess you wanted this:

```
$scope.Json = JSON.parse({ Id:"5464", Class:"9", Rank:"4" }) ;
```

Once you have this, you can add the element you want as:

```
$scope.Json.Name = "Vicky" ;
```