# how to add an element inside a json array at the specific index in a repeating block?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am trying to add element "delete:true" after each occurrence of "_rev " mentioned in the below sample request.

Original Request:

```
{
    "docs": [
        {
            "_id": "123",
            "_rev": "1-7836",
            },
        {
            "_id": "456",
            "_rev": "1-1192",
           }
         ]                         

}
```

Expected Request:

```
{
    "docs": [
        {
            "_id": "123",
            "_rev": "1-7836",
            "_deleted" :true
            },
        {
            "_id": "456",
            "_rev": "1-1192",
            "_deleted" :true
           }
         ]                         

}
```

When I tried the below code,the ""_deleted" :true" is getting inserted after the -rev element is closed. PFB for the same and suggest.

```
function main(params) {
for (var i = 0; i< params.docs.length; i++) {
for (var value in params.docs[i]) {
if(value == '_rev'  && params.docs[i]._rev ){ 
var string1 = JSON.stringify(params.docs[i]);
var str = ',';
var string2 = '"';
var string3 =str+string2+ '_deleted'+ string2+ ':' + "true" ;
var res =  string1 + string3  ;
}
}
}
}
  ######################
[
  "2018-01-23T09:44:23.568738362Z stdout:
  {\"_id\":\"123\",
  \"_rev\":\"1-7836\"},
  \"_deleted\":true"]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add new attribute (element) to JSON object using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736590/add-new-attribute-element-to-json-object-using-javascript)

Comment: What for you need the position? JSON is an **J**ava **S**cript **O**bject **N**otaion. In my opinion the position should be of no account ..

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` and `Object.assign` instead of generating a string

```
var output = params.docs.map( s => Object.assign( {}, {"_deleted" :true}, s ) );
```

You can then convert this to string using `JSON.stringify( output );`

**Demo**

```js
var params = {
  "docs": [{
      "_id": "123",
      "_rev": "1-7836",
    },
    {
      "_id": "456",
      "_rev": "1-1192",
    }
  ]
};
var output = params.docs.map(s => Object.assign({}, {
  "_deleted": true
}, s));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = {
    "docs": [
        {
            "_id": "123",
            "_rev": "1-7836",
            },
        {
            "_id": "456",
            "_rev": "1-1192",
           }
         ]                         

}
var newData = data['docs'].map(item => {
   item._delete = true
   return item
})

console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply put ._deleted attribute to doc, like this ?

```
function main(params) {
  for (var i = 0; i< params.docs.length; i++) {
    params.docs[i]._deleted = true;
    var res = JSON.stringify(params.docs[i]);
  }
 }
}
```

Or like this :

```
function main(params) {
  for (var i = 0; i< params.docs.length; i++) {
    params.docs[i]["_deleted"] = true;
    var res = JSON.stringify(params.docs[i]);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the not existing attribute directly and assign an value:

```
#!/usr/bin/js

var myJSON = { "docs": [ { "_id":"123", "_rev":"1-200" } ] }
console.log(myJSON);
myJSON.docs[0]["_deleted"]=true;
console.log(myJSON);
```

Output of example:

```
# js append.js 
{ docs: [ { _id: '123', _rev: '1-200' } ] }
{ docs: [ { _id: '123', _rev: '1-200', _deleted: true } ] }
```

Read the more extensive example here: [Add new attribute (element) to JSON object using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736590/add-new-attribute-element-to-json-object-using-javascript)

So this might be a duplicate ...

Comment: I've read the given link again. It lacks the OPs question for the position. But what for the position is relevant inside object notation ... ?

Answer (score 0):

**This is worked for me!:**

```
     let data = {
  docs: [
    {
      _id: "123",
      _rev: "1-7836",
    },
    {
      _id: "456",
      _rev: "1-1192",
    },
  ],
};

const array = data.docs.map((item) => {
  item._deleted = true;
  return item;
});

console.log("RESULT>>>>>", array);
```

Result:

```
{
    "docs": [
        {
            "_id": "123",
            "_rev": "1-7836",
            "_deleted" :true
            },
        {
            "_id": "456",
            "_rev": "1-1192",
            "_deleted" :true
           }
         ]                         

}
```

To add an element inside the 0th index of the array:

```
data.docs[0]._deleted = true;
```

To add an element by conditionally

```
let specificId=456

data.docs.map((item) =>
specificId === item._id?(item._deleted = true):(item._deleted =false)
```