# Add a property into a JSON object JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this JSON:

```
{
"id": 10,
"name": "Color test2",
"seed_id": 1,
"season_id": 2,
"description": null,
"work_schedule_type_id": 2,
"color": "#00A946",
"active": false,
"starred": true,
"phases": [{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Phase2",
    "work_schedule_type_id": 2,
    "phase_color": "#343434",
    "phase_order_of_operations": 1,
    "description": "TEST PHASE TYPE2",
    "isExpanded": false,
    "$$hashKey": "object:1387"
}]
```

}

I need add a property `tasks` for each phase in phases. How I can do this?

Comment: What information will have the task?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736590/add-new-attribute-element-to-json-object-using-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach adds the `tasks` from an Array.

```js
var obj = {
  "id": 10,
  "name": "Color test2",
  "seed_id": 1,
  "season_id": 2,
  "description": null,
  "work_schedule_type_id": 2,
  "color": "#00A946",
  "active": false,
  "starred": true,
  "phases": [{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Phase2",
    "work_schedule_type_id": 2,
    "phase_color": "#343434",
    "phase_order_of_operations": 1,
    "description": "TEST PHASE TYPE2",
    "isExpanded": false,
    "$$hashKey": "object:1387"
  }]
}

var tasks = ["Task1", "Task2"];
obj.phases.forEach(p => p.tasks = tasks);

console.log(obj.phases);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
angular.forEach(obj.phases, function(item) { item.tasks = your_val } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your JSON object is named json, the code would look something like this:

```
for (phase of json.phases) {
    phase.task = "somevalue";
}
```