# Update nested json data with underscore

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have a json looking like so:

```
{
    "itemsList": [{
        "id": 187994,
        "contentName": "Content",
        "contentItems": [{
            "name": "nested 1",
            "description": "<p>nested 1</p>\n"
        }, {
            "name": "nested 2 ",
            "description": "<p>nested 2</p>\n"
        }]
    }]
}
```

And I am importing this data to an update form and trying to update the value for **nested 1** when I submit the form but it keeps only the updated value, somehow it keeps only the updated value the other values get wiped out.

The function below updates the contentItems object but it keeps only the updated content:

```
$("#editResourceItemForm").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.getJSON(appDirLocation + "public/_data/resource_data.json", function (jsonData) {

                console.log(jsonData.itemsList.contentItem);

                //var contentItems = jsonData.itemsList.contentItems;
                var resourceId = $("#editResourceItemForm input#resourceId").val(); // resource id
                var updatedContentName = $("#appData").data("content-name");
                var updatedContentItem = {
                                name: $("#editResourceItemForm input#contentItemName").val(),
                                description: CKEDITOR.instances.contentItemDescription.getData()
                };

                resourceId = Number(resourceId); // input filed is collected as string needs to make number

                _.each(jsonData.itemsList, function (item) {
                    if (item.id === resourceId) {
                        item.contentName = updatedContentName;
                        item.contentItems = updatedContentItem ;
                        // queue here new items to update 
                    }
                }); // used underscore.js seems better for handling json data

                var newJsonOutput = JSON.stringify(jsonData); //stringify new data

                var jsonFile = new BCAPI.Models.FileSystem.File(appDirLocation + "public/_data/resource_data.json");

                jsonFile.upload(newJsonOutput).done(function () {
                    $("#contentItemsList").html(""); //clear old data to load new
                    console.log("RESOURCE DATA UPDATED");
                    $('#editResourceItem').foundation('close'); //close reveal after created and saved file
                    renderResourceItems(resourceId);
                }).fail(function (jqXHR) {
                    console.log("RESOURCES JSON FAILED UPDATE: " + jqXHR.responseText);
                }); // END OF JSON CREATING

                console.log(newJsonOutput);

            }).done(function (dataprocessed) {
                console.log(dataprocessed);
            }).fail(function (jqXHR) {
                console.log("Request failed." + "Error code: " + jqXHR.status + "Error text: " + jqXHR.statusText + "Response text: " + jqXHR.responseText);
            });

        });
```

Please let me know what I can do to pass the updated values to the existing contentItems without wiping out the rest of the data in the object.

This is the fiddle I used to create the data:
[https://jsfiddle.net/RicardoAlves/zb5dprvv](https://jsfiddle.net/RicardoAlves/zb5dprvv/2/)

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736590/add-new-attribute-element-to-json-object-using-javascript. Is this helpful?

Comment: the examples there is to add, I am looking to update the current value on the nested json object

Comment: Please update question to include only relevant code. Maybe make a fiddle out of it.

Comment: If you update something, old value is replaced by the new one. It is unclear what you want. Can you provide a sample input and output?

Comment: at the same time I update the current data I can't figure out how to keep the old data and just push a new value to the contentItems object