# How do I add more information to an object?

Tags: javascript

Let us suppose I have the following object:

```
{
    foo: "bar"
}
```

How do I, *using javascript*, make it:

```
{
    foo: "bar",
    bar: "foo"
}
```

Comment: `const obj = {
foo: "bar"
}; obj.bar = "foo";` Read about dot notation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736590/add-new-attribute-element-to-json-object-using-javascript

Comment: There is no such thing as "JSON object". [JSON](https://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure (usually an object or an array). It needs to be parsed in order to re-create data structures similar to those used to create it. There is no JSON in your question, only a Javascript object. Read about [objects in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: When I use this method, I get an error that the element is not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to assign it a new property using **dot notation**:

```js
const data = {
  foo: "bar"
};

data.bar = 'foo';

console.log(data);
```

If your property names are variables, use **bracket notation** instead:

```js
const data = {
  foo: "bar"
};

const newProp = 'bar';
data[newProp] = 'foo';

console.log(data);
```

See the doc on [property accessors here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Comment: Good answer! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to create new key by reversing the actual key and value. In that case use `Object.keys` which will give an array and create new keys based on that

```js
let data = {
  foo: "bar"
}

Object.keys(data).forEach((item) => {
  data[data[item]] = item


});


console.log(data)
```