# How to dynamically add object inside json array?

Tags: json, angular

I'm trying to dynamically add an object inside every object which is present in my json array. But I'm unable to do so. My object is getting appended at the end of json which is not what I want.

```
jsonArray:any=[
    {
        "id": 1000,
        "body": "some comment",
        "postId": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "body": "some comment",
        "postId": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "body": "some comment",
        "postId": 1
    }
]

selectFLag:any={"selected":"true"}

temArray:any;

learnJSONPArse()
{
    for (var i = 0; this.jsonArray.length > i; i++) 
    {
        Alert(this.jsonArray.length)
    }
}

this.jsonArray.push(this.selectFLag)
```

-----expected output is

```
[
    {
        "id": 1000,
        "body": "some comment",
        "postId": 1,
        "selected":"true"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "body": "some comment",
        "postId": 1,
        "selected":"true"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "body": "some comment",
        "postId": 1,
        "selected":"true"
    }
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add new attribute (element) to JSON object using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736590/add-new-attribute-element-to-json-object-using-javascript)

Comment: Try this: `this.sonArray.forEach(x => x.selected = true);`

Comment: Please show a minimal reproduction of the issue you are having with desired input and output.

Comment: @KeenanDiggs desired input [

{

"id": 1000,

"body": "some comment",

"postId": 1

},

{

"id": 2,

"body": "some comment",

"postId": 1

},

{

"id": 3,

"body": "some comment",

"postId": 1

}

]

Comment: @KeenanDiggs desired output [

{

"id": 1000,

"body": "some comment",

"postId": 1,

"selected":"true"
},

{

"id": 2,

"body": "some comment",

"postId": 1,

"selected":"true"
},

{

"id": 3,

"body": "some comment",

"postId": 1,

"selected":"true"
}

]

Answer (score 0):

You're question is a little unclear, but it sounds like you want to `map` each item in your array to a new item. The new item is the same as the old one, but `assign`ed an additional property.

If so, something like this could work for you:

```
const objToAppend = { selected: true };
jsonArray.map(item => Object.assign(item, objToAppend));
```

Refs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map