# How to add new attribute to JSON object using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

How do I add new attribute to JSON object using JavaScript?
I want to add a new attribute to JSON object.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736590/add-new-attribute-element-to-json-object-using-javascript is this what you're asking?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736590/add-new-attribute-element-to-json-object-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation. A JSON object is really a string that has yet to be turned into the object it represents.

To add a property to an existing object in JS you could do the following.

```
object["property"] = value;
```

or

```
object.property = value;
```

If you provide some extra info like exactly what you need to do in context you might get a more tailored answer.